# Machine confused as to version of LibreOffice running

Tags: libreoffice, centos-7

I have a CentOS machine that had LibreOffice installed. Natively it is running 5.3, however I manually installed 7.1. When I open a document, The splash screen for 5.3 loads, then the menu bar lists '7.1' as the running application, while the About box also lists 5.3. How can I be sure which version is running and make sure it is always 7.1?

Comment: Uninstall v5.3?

Comment: Simple answers are the best, however I have struggled to figure out how to install something that comes default with CentOS, and be sure that I'm uninstalling the correct version as well.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be via whatever package manager comes with it?

Comment: You might have to uninstall both, and then reinstall 7.1; there were times I had to do similar for Windows.

Comment: I'll look into it. The terminal package manager is yum, but the software installer in the GUI suggested something like 1.3 is installed, and I don't know if there is some useful mapping between that version number and the installed.